# How to Mapping Columns in a Self-Join table!

Tags: sql, sql-server, mapping, parent-child, self-join

I have a parent/child table and want to update Its PK and FK to new values. the problem is that oldParent Ids Should Sync with new ones matching with Old Ids. so:

I have this data as a temp table:

```
OldID |  OldParentID |  NewID | NewParentID
  1         0            10         NULL
  2         0            11         NULL
  3         2            13         NULL
  4         3            14         NULL
```

and I Need Update NewParentID as Follows:

```
OldID |  OldParentID |  NewID | NewParentID
  1         0            10         0
  2         0            11         0
  3         2            13         11
  4         3            14         13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  OldID int, 
  OldParentID int, 
  NewID int, 
  NewParentID int
)

insert into @T 
select 1, 0, 10, null union all
select 2, 0, 11, null union all
select 3, 2, 13, null union all
select 4, 3, 14, null

update T1
  set T1.NewParentID = coalesce(T2.NewID, 0)
from @T as T1
  left outer join @T as T2
    on T1.OldParentID = T2.OldID
```